# MongoDB python how parse multi-level json

Tags: python, json, mongodb, parsing, flask

how parse multi-level json data, in Mongodb with Python 3.5?

```
PLAYER_DEFAULT = {
"_id": Inc(PlayersDB),
"mail": "test@gmail.com",
"password": "123456",
"token": uuid4().hex,
"username": "applet",
"user_info":
    {
        "show_name" : "Hero",
        "rate_us": 20000,
        "rating": 300,
        "gcg": "",
        "ration":0,
        "items":
            [
                {"id":1, "item_type":"socket",      "name":"aEveA", "data":{"level":1, "stat":"AVA"}},
                {"id":2, "item_type":"socket",      "name":"aEveA", "data":{"level":4, "stat":"AVA"}},
                {"id":3, "item_type":"socket",      "name":"Hestos", "data":{"level":9, "stat":"Hest"}},
                {"id":4, "item_type":"user", "name":"AAACZX",   "data":{"expr":1000}},
                {"id":5, "item_type":"user", "name":"AAAAZZZCX",   "data":        {"expr":1000}}
               ]
        } 
}
```

how get data level and stat in items?

```
["_id"]->["show_name"]  
["_id"]->["user_info"]->["items"]   
["_id"]->["user_info"]->["items"] -> get value by "stat" in items[0]
```

me need get items id, by items "stat" value
i use loop
how get x count?

```
for x in PlayersDB.find({"_id":1}):  
    print(x["user_info"]["items"][x.count()])
```

And... how to update "item_type", by "id", in "items"?
And how to delete 1 docuement by "id":1 in "items"?

Comment: do you have any code to show?

Comment: what is your `[key1]->[key2]` notation trying to show?

Comment: Screenshots are useless; can you not paste the json document into your question?

Comment: how paste text and format text to json?

Comment: "_id" is guaranteed to be a unique key, so there will only ever be just 1 matching doc.  And, really? You figured out how to paste code, but can't paste json?

Comment: I thought that the parser does not recognize the format json.

Comment: I'm guessing "player_info" actually means "user_info", and "inventory" means "items"?  Do you know how to get the `len`gth of a list?

Comment: yes, "player_info" = "user_info", and "invetnory" = "items",
yes, i get len by len(list()), example ->
i get this last index by usersdb 
len(usersdb.find().sort("_id",-1)[0]["user_info"]["items"]) - 1

Comment: me need delete inner docuement, by id 1

Answer (score 1):

For that document, try:

```
doc['user_info']['items'][0]['data']['stat']
```

If you have a doc for a player, and want to count how many items that player has, you will use some built-in Python function, which I will call `XXX`, and which you should research to see what that function is, and use it on the `items` attribute of the doc:

```
number_of_items = XXX(doc['user_info']['items'])
```

And in future, please use the same names and structure in your question as in your posted examples.

Comment: If that is a doc fetched using pymongo, then it will already have been `loads`ed.

Comment: sorry, need get "stat", by value, example...

Comment: doc['user_info']['items'][0][{"stat":"Hest"}]

Comment: That does not match your posted example. In `doc['user_info']['items'][0]`, there is a 'data' field: `"data": {"level": 1, "stat": "Hest"}`.  Hence, to get the value of stat for the first item, use: `doc['user_info']['items'][0]['data']['stat']`. To get the level, use: `doc['user_info']['items'][0]['data']['level']`.